# Is there an idiomatic way to convert from `void*`?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture

I keep running across a problem where some middleware is reading from some data source (usually in the form of a void pointer), and transforming it into some useful type.

The design pattern that's always used to solve this problem resembles the following:

Many different standalone data types that represent messages:

```cpp
struct Type_A { 
  int value; 
};

struct Type_B { 
  int number;
  bool value; 
};

struct Type_C { 
  double value;
  std::string word; 
};
```

Some data stream (`message_queue`) I don't have control over that feeds me a type hint and raw bytes I must convert and do some similar but slightly different operations across all types.

```cpp
// Pushed elsewhere asynchronously
std::queue<std::pair<MessageTypes, void*>> message_queue;

void process_messages(void) {
  while (true) {
    if (!message_queue.empty()) {
      // omitting thread safety stuff for simplicity's sake
      msg = message_queue.front();
      message_queue.pop();
      type = msg.first;
      content = msg.second;
      
      switch (type) {
        case MessageTypes::TYPE_A:
          auto typed_msg = std::static_pointer_cast<Type_A>(content);
          std::cout << typed_msg.value << std::endl;
          break;
        case MessageTypes::TYPE_B:
          auto typed_msg = std::static_pointer_cast<Type_B>(content);
          std::cout << typed_msg.number << std::endl;
          std::cout << typed_msg.value << std::endl;
          break;
        case MessageTypes::TYPE_C:
          auto typed_msg = std::static_pointer_cast<Type_C>(content);
          std::cout << typed_msg.value << std::endl;
          std::cout << typed_msg.word << std::endl;
          break;
        ...etc.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where `do_something` takes some interface class that all the types implement. The identical cases go on and on as there are many different types the data could be.

To me this smells because of all the duplicate code. That said, I'm not sure of a better way to convert from a `void*`. Additionally since I've seen this problem in multiple places, I was wondering if there was a idiomatic way to solve this problem in c++, or perhaps this is it and that's why I keep seeing it?

Comment: Ideally you should get rid of the `void*` and use concrete types the entire way.  Without knowing what exactly you are doing, that's about as much help as I can give.  You may possibly want a `std::variant` or `std::any` and then use the visitor pattern via `std::visit` to do the dispatch.

Comment: `Where do_something either takes another void* ` why do you cast than?

Comment: This is typical C message cracker ported to C++.  Since this is "middleware", unless you are the middleware author, I would not try to "fix" it.  If it's a good middleware library and has been tested, and passes, you definitely don't need to tweak it.  @SergeyA I'm guessing `do_something` is overloaded based on Type_A vs. Type_B (strongly typed methods), not another single `void *` method.

Comment: @franji1 I do not understand your point. Where is this extra `void*` coming from?

Comment: @SergeyA assorted reasons. Do something in this thread before pushing it to another. Sometimes `do_something` is replaced with a similar sequence operations like printing part of the message or some marshalling operation.

Comment: @franji1 what if I am responsible for maintaining/expanding the library, is there a better solution to "fix" it? i.e. make it more extensible and maintainable?

Comment: @SergeyA  Since this is not the actual code, I was guessing that do_something is actually based on the type conversion, not just another void * method/methods (i.e. what it's "cracking" to).

Comment: @TenderShortGoldenRetriever my point is that if `do_something` accepts void pointer, the casting there is moot. If you want meaningful answers, you need to provide meaningful code. @franji1 - according to OP, this is actual `void*`-accepting function.

Comment: @SergeyA - OP may be right in describing the code, but typically crackers do all this message cracking/type casting, so that you resolve the void * to actual pointers.  Like you said, we need to see an actual example of the cracker code AND the `do_something` methods.

Comment: @SergeyA @franji1 I changed it to a more specific example. Instead of `do_something` let's just say some similar but slightly different actions tailored to each type. Writing that down, it sounds like the types should inherit from some interface class to do the action. But that still leaves the question of the "cracking/typecasting"

Comment: In this case, the giant switch case like that is standard thing.